# Creating Stored Procedure with CASE statement that determine the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure that contains a `CASE` statement. However, I need to select it depending on my parameter that parameter defines the column not the value.

Is that possible?

Here's what I've tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HR.GetRequestByPriv
    @colKey VARCHAR(50)
AS
    DECLARE @empName VARCHAR(100)

    SELECT       
       @empName = (HR.EmployeeRec.fname  + ' ' + HR.EmployeeRec.lname)
    FROM            
       HR.LeaveRec 
    INNER JOIN
       HR.EmployeeRec ON HR.LeaveRec.EmployeeRecNo = HR.EmployeeRec.recno
    WHERE
        CASE
            WHEN @colKey = 'isApprove' THEN HR.LeaveRec.isApprove
            WHEN @colKey = 'isNote' THEN HR.LeaveRec.isNote
            WHEN @colKey = 'isVerify' THEN HR.LeaveRec.isVerify
        END = 0

    RETURN @empName
```

Hoping for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The part of your code where you choose a column that must be zero looks fine.

But [a stored procedure return value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) is always an integer.  So this won't work:

```
create procedure dbo.YourSP
as
declare @var varchar(50)
select @var = 'Oops this won''t work'
return @var -- Since @var is not an integer, this won't work as expected
```

The usual approach is to return a rowset.  Any `select` that does not assign variables returns a rowset.  For example:

```
create procedure dbo.YourSP
as
select 'Returning a rowset'
```

Another option is an output parameter:

```
create procedure dbo.YourSP
    @var varchar(50) output
as
select @var = 'Returning an output parameter'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused.  You say you want a stored procedure but you are returning something.  Andomar has one solution which is an output parameter.  I suspect that you really want a function.  In this case, you can create a single-statement, table-valued function, which is much like a view that takes arguments:

```
CREATE FUNCTION HR.GetRequestByPriv (
    @colKey VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE as
RETURN(SELECT (l.fname  + ' ' + l.lname) as EmpName
       FROM HR.LeaveRec l NNER JOIN
            HR.EmployeeRec e
            ON l.EmployeeRecNo = e.recno
       WHERE (@colKey = 'isApprove' AND HR.LeaveRec.isApprove = 0) OR
             (@colKey = 'isNote' AND HR.LeaveRec.isNote = 0) OR
             (@colKey = 'isVerify' AND HR.LeaveRec.isVerify)
      );
```

You can then call this in a `select` statement as:

```
select *
from HR.GetRequestByPriv('isNote');
```

Comment: Nice, but when i executed the function using table adapter it says that 

Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvpxfdymjsqigle/Screenshot%202014-08-16%2021.59.41.png

Result on previewing the data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/locuw9a72cc38i6/Screenshot%202014-08-16%2022.03.50.png

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for this kind of small procedure would be to use `IF`. Use 3 different SELECT statements in 3 `IF`/`ELSE` blocks and that's it. Like this:

```
IF @colKey = 'isApprove' 
    SELECT       @empName = (HR.EmployeeRec.fname  + ' ' + HR.EmployeeRec.lname)
    FROM  HR.LeaveRec INNER JOIN HR.EmployeeRec ON HR.LeaveRec.EmployeeRecNo = HR.EmployeeRec.recno
    WHERE HR.LeaveRec.isApprove = 0
ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @colKey = 'isNote'
           SELECT       @empName = (HR.EmployeeRec.fname  + ' ' + HR.EmployeeRec.lname)
           FROM  HR.LeaveRec INNER JOIN HR.EmployeeRec ON HR.LeaveRec.EmployeeRecNo = HR.EmployeeRec.recno
            WHERE HR.LeaveRec.isNote = 0
        ELSE
            ...
    END
```